# Python functions with dots

Tags: python

I have defined a of ordered pairs called `f` and defined a function `applyfunction` that goes through the ordered pairs looking at the first value to compare and when it does match to print the second value.

```
f = {(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,8)}


def applyfunction (f,x):
    for xy in f:
        if xy[0]==x:
            print(xy[1])


applyfunction(f,3)
```

The above works just the way I want it to. In the meantime I have seen that in python there are functions that have a dot notation and I think that would be useful here. So my question, how can I rewrite the `applyfunction` definition such that I can use the following notation: `f.applyfunction(3)`?

Comment: Those are called methods.  They are class attributes.  When invoked through a class instance, they become bound methods, with the first argument bound to the class instance.  So your question is, "Would defining a class help my application?"

Comment: I think you're asking how you can add the applyfunction function as a method to sets. Don't do that, just use the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I only want this is a one off way to show the idea of going from a set of ordered pairs to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the ordered pairs into a class of your own, which has the method (method == a function inside a class) you mentioned inside of it.

```
class OrderedPairWrapper():
    
    def __init__(self, op):
        self.op = op
    
    def applyfunction (self, x):
        for xy in self.op:
            if xy[0]==x:
                print(xy[1])

f = {(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,8)}
f = OrderedPairWrapper(f)

print(f.applyfunction(3))
# 6
```

Comment: Note that this sort of thing (*"two methods, one of which is `__init__`"*) is canonically when to [stop writing classes](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think so too, but I also think he just wanted an example to get his head around this dot methods in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Dots are used to access methods of a class using its object name. If you want to access that using dot operator, create an object called f for a class with a method applyfunction. Then you can accomplish your desired task